# android media - mediacontrol for playing audio as a service

Tags: android

I want to play the audio in my android app as a service so it keeps playing while the user goes to other applications. I managed to develop the core parts of the service yet now i need controls on the side of the application to start/stop the audio. I would love to use the MediaControl class yet it seems to be bound to a mediaplayer defined in the same application. So basically I am trying to find out how to connect a service based audio playback with a mediacontroller or something similar.

Any advice highly appreciated

martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself.

Instead of connecting the MediaController with an actual instance of MediaPlayer you can just implement the interface MediaPlayerControl with whatever class and connect the service with the MediaController widget through the interface methods.